# How do I send text messages multiple recipients on CyanogenMod 9?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms

How do I send text messages to multiple recipients on  CyanogenMod 9? I don't see any contacts icon in my messaging app i.e, ICS Messaging App. Is there any way to do it? I am using an HTC Wildfire S.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a contact picker per se.

After you type in one contact, type a comma and start typing the name of another. Separate multiple contacts by commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not found any clue, Handset SMS do that, see Android store : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en

Comment: OP is asking about the stock messaging app @sputnick

Comment: POST edited accordingly. What mean OP Sparx ?

Comment: Original Poster - the author of the question.